# How to left align a text without removing the indentations?

Tags: indentation

How do I left-align a text starting with the Introduction (until the very end: Appendix) without removing the indentations?

Comment: To be more clear, can you explain your requirement in more detail with a `MWE`?

Comment: It is not at all clear wah tyou desire. It is highly recomended to provide a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that reproduces the problem. If you don't want indented paragraphs and instead want a blank line between them, you can include `\usepackage{parskip}`. If that is not what you want, we need more info to be able to help you.

Comment: Basically the right side of the text should not be justified. I want it to hang like in chicago style

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just reset the indentation after specifying raggedright

```
\raggedright
\setlength\parindent{15pt}
```

Comment: it somehow does not work. This error comes up ! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.203 \vspace{0.5cm} \\

Comment: @KarlL. you should not have `\\ ` there (but as that is code not mentioned in your question that is a separate issue)

Comment: @KarlL. you should almost never have `\vspace ` or `\\ ` (outside tables) in a document, what  is this code intended to produce?

Comment: I intened to produce my own titlepage: \begin{titlepage} ... I only used \vspace in there. However, maybe it would be possible to let this comment run after the title page? How would that work?

Comment: @KarlL. you could start `\raggedright` at any point in the document, however the error is completely unrelated to this question,  the error is showing you have used  `\\ ` to end a line at a point where there is no line, but that would happen whether or not you have set `\parindent` as shown in this answer and is in code that you have not shown.   If you want help with an error, make a small complete document that shows the error and ask a question about that error including the test document in a code block. I really can not guess how to fix code that I have not seen.

Comment: Sorry my mistake I put it in the preamble ... I was wrong! Works fine, thanks!